# Oracle ADF many-to-many with additional attribute

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm developing a ADF Fusion Web Application and have some problems with EntityAssociations and ViewLinks.

I have a database table `Project` with id, name etc. Also I have a table `Technology` which only contains a id and the name of the technology, for example "ADF".
The relationship between theese two entities is many-to-many. Means one project can have multiple technologies assigned and inverse a technology can be assigned to multiple projects.

This relationship is described trough a join table named `Project_Technology`. Columns of this table are `Project_FK, Technology_FK and Effort`. Project_FK and Technology_FK are a composite primary key, Effort is an additional attribute.

Can someone explain me how to map EntityObject and ViewObjects that I can access the Effort, too? "Regular" many-to-many associations aren't that hard to implement but I am really struggling with the additional attribute.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I could solve my issues. See answer below for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.
The Problem was the composite primary key on my join tables. It seems like ADF doesn't like them. I put a extra column `ID` on the join tables and now I can insert values by using the `CreateInsert` Data Controls.